# Build Android Cordova Android-Sdk Deprecated

Tags: java, cordova

I want to build cordova androd app, when i run cordova build, its return error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/adam/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 16.0.2
```

My android SDK is deprecated, i have already source the sdk on my zhsrc file, but its still not working

My zhsrc file

```
export PATH=/Users/adam/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android SDK is not deprecated, but the ANDROID_HOME variable is, as explained here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/949
In the meantime, set both variables.

You also run into the error of not matching JDK versions. Although 16.0 might be a fit, cordova looks for a version that name matches '1.8....', check yours with `java -version`.
This took me a few hours, now I replaced Java 18 with JDK 1.8. and it works.

The answer is late but hopefully still helpful.